# "Verify with me" vs. "verify for me"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, prepositions

Which would be more appropriate when asking for address verification:

> - Can you verify with me you mailing address?
> - Can you verify for me your mailing address?

Though I believe this requires no preposition, so "Can you verify your mailing address?" would sound sensible as well.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you verify *with* me your mailing address?

This can mean one of two things. It can mean that the two of you together will verify their mailing address (like "Will you walk *with* me?"), or it can mean that you will possess the verification when they are done doing it (like "my account is verified *with* PayPal.").

> Can you verify for me your mailing address?

That means that they will perform the verification because you require it.

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach is "for me" and you can check this kind of thing in the future by moving "for me" to the end. This is also the more common form of the question:

> Can you verify your mailing address for me?

"With me" would be used in different circumstances — usually involving a different person or company:

> Can you verify your mailing address with Yahoo/Google/Microsoft?
>
> Can you verify your mailing address with Alice?

---

Your other comment is true, by the way. This is fine:

> Can you verify your mailing address?

Comment: +1 though I wouldn't call _with me_ incorrect, it just does not mean what the OP wants to say. If we were to sit down and verify something together you weould be verifying it _with me_.

Comment: Yes, good point. Do you think WRONG/RIGHT would be less confusing?

Comment: I would just explain that _with me_ means something else.

Comment: Moreover, ‘with’ would be the appropriate preposition if you were verifying the (existence/validity of the) e-mail address with Yahoo!/Google/Microsoft (or whoever provides the e-mail).

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:

> Dear John.
>   You know how I hate to write.
>   But you must verify with me tonight.
>   You had me acquire you a new web site.
>   You gave your clients the wrong address, how bright.
>   Please verify with me the address of your web site.
>   So that you could provide your clients with an address that's right.

Case 2:

> Dear Joan.
>   I know how you hate to write.
>   But you must verify for me tonight.
>   You had acquired me a new web site.
>   But you gave me its wrong address, how bright.
>   Speak to the customer support you might
>   And verify for me the address of the site.
>   So that I could provide my clients an address that's right.

Case 3:

> Dear John.
>   We know how we hate to meet.
>   But tomorrow we must be on our feet.
>   That our new clients we should greet.
>   Please come with me and be dressed neat.
>   I need you to verify their address with me, with Pete.
>   I don't like speaking to Pete by myself, that piece of meat.

Answer (score 0):

The question appears to be which phrase, "verify for" or "verify with," is correct. The correct one for the person or people asking for verification would be "verify for," as in "verify for me/us." It doesn't really need to be used, though; the "for me/us" is understood in this case. "Verify...with" would be rarely used, but could be correct if it were used in an imperative format, as in, "Please verify that these figures are correct with Accounts Payable." This is telling someone where they must go, or to whom they must speak in order to perform the verification. ***HOWEVER***, unless you are asking someone to take a look at something written down, or listen to something being said to verify its truthfulness or accuracy, it is ***NEVER*** correct to ask someone to verify something if there is nothing for them to either hear or see. "Verify" is ***NOT*** a synonym for "tell me." When the person on the phone, or the pharmacy cash register says, "Can you please verify your address (or birth date, or what-have-you)" without either showing you something or speaking it aloud, he or she is asking the impossible of you. The best synonym for verify would be "check," and if you have nothing to check, you cannot verify. The better question would be something like, "To verify that I have the correct Mary Smith file, please tell me your address." Verify can be replaced easily and correctly with either "make sure" or "check," so it would be correct in that sentence. The best rule to follow in speech and composition is that if you are unsure of the word, find a different one!